# Getting Days, Hours and Minutes between two dates with their respective time stamps

Tags: mysql, sql, otrs

I am creating a query for OTRS which is installed on either mysql or postgres. 
I have the following datetime format: `NOW() = 2016-06-02 09:23:01, t.createtime = 2015-11-26 09:41:02`

I am trying to calculate the days, hours and minutes between the date/time fields.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT q.name as QueueName, t.tn as TicketNumber, t.title, ts.name as Status, tp.name as Priority, 
DATEDIFF(NOW(), t.create_time),
NOW(),
t.create_time

FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN ticket_state ts on ts.id = t.ticket_state_id
LEFT JOIN ticket_priority tp on tp.id = t.ticket_priority_id
LEFT JOIN queue q on q.id = t.queue_id
WHERE 
ts.type_id NOT IN (3) 
and ts.type_id NOT IN (7)
```

How would I go about doing this. I tried the age function it doesn't seem t be supported. I also tried this:

```
CONCAT(
FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), t.create_time)) / 24), ' days ',
MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), t.create_time)), 24), ' hours ',
MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), t.create_time)), ' minutes') as Age
```

This does not seem to be accurate either. What am i doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Well it can be configured with both. I believe it's MySql.

Answer (score 3):

Your question has nothing to do with OTRS but with the database you are using.

On MySQL, you should probably use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` - you used `TIMEDIFF()` but that returns a `TIME` and those can not be larger than 839 hours.

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, TIMESTAMP('2016-06-04 00:00:00'), NOW()) AS days,
  MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, TIMESTAMP('2016-06-04 00:00:00'), NOW()), 24) AS hours,
  MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIMESTAMP('2016-06-04'), NOW()), 60) AS minutes;
```

On PostgreSQL, you can use `AGE()` and `DATE_PART()` to retrieve the difference in units you specify in PostgreSQL. `AGE()` takes two timestamps and returns an interval.

```
SELECT DATE_PART('month', AGE(NOW(), TIMESTAMP '2016-04-19 10:23:54')) AS months,
       DATE_PART('hour',  AGE(NOW(), TIMESTAMP '2016-04-19 10:23:54')) AS hours,
       DATE_PART('day',   AGE(NOW(), TIMESTAMP '2016-04-19 10:23:54')) AS days,
       DATE_PART('hour',  AGE(NOW(), TIMESTAMP '2016-04-19 10:23:54')) AS hours;
```

Comment: I cannot utilize the AGE function.

Comment: That would be because you're not using PostgreSQL but MySQL. I've updated my answer to include a MySQL example.